# Ionic V4 app doesn't work on android 4.4.2 but it was working

Tags: android, api, ionic-framework

I have developed an android app in ionic v4 and it was working on android 4.4.2 kernal. But after i changed something, I doesn't work. I might be because, I changed android api platform a long ago. So, I hope that it will work if switch the api to api 19. But i don't know how to do so. anyone help me on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged "ionic-framework" I am going to assume, that you use Ionic Framework along with cordova.
If so, you have a file named `config.xml` the root folder of your project. There you can set a preference with the android min-sdk-version like so:

```
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="19" />
```

Also see [here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/9.x/config_ref/index.html#preference) for reference.